# I want to pass my SSO user in the S3 bucket policy, how to add. It is not IAM user

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

My S3 bucket policy is

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Deny",
            "NotPrincipal": {
                "AWS": [
                    "arn:aws:iam::035452602320:user/abc.dev",
                    "arn:aws:iam::035452602320:user/lmn.dev",
                    "arn:aws:iam::035452602320:user/pqr.dev",
    
                ]
            },
            "Action": "s3:*",
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::abc",
                "arn:aws:s3:::abc/*"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

I want to add my SSO user along with IAM users, I tried like

```
""arn:aws:sts::035452602320:assumed-role/AWSReservedSSO_Devops_New_610980ed099cb31f/upasana.ghase"
```

but not working, Also tried to add condition in policy like,

```
"Condition": {
                "StringLike": {
                    "aws:userId": "AWSReservedSSO_AmazonRDS-Superuser_f0d2b8a5c8e6b489:upasana.ghase"
                }
            }
```

But this is also not working for me, how to do this.

```
"Condition": {
                "StringLike": {
                    "aws:userId": "AWSReservedSSO_AmazonRDS-Superuser_f0d2b8a5c8e6b489:upasana.ghase"
                }
            }
```

I tried adding the condition in policy but its not working.

Comment: Did you try to put ARN into `Principal`?

Answer (score 0):

Here's how you can specify the SSO user. This works for me.

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Deny",
            "Principal": "*",
            "Action": [
                "s3:*"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::my-bucket/*",
                "arn:aws:s3:::my-bucket"
            ]
            "Condition": {
                "StringLike": {
                    "aws:userid": "<RoleId>:<SSOUserName>"
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

To get the `RoleId`:

```
aws iam get-role --role-name {SSO-Role-Name}
        "RoleId": "ARO*******",
```

`SSOUserName` the user's SSO user.

PS: Remove sensitive information such as AWS Account ID, exact IAM role name/arn, and username.